# Merge record of two seperate collection using aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two separate collection let's say collA and collB. Both have some common fields let's say fieldA, fieldB, fieldC are available in both collection.

```
db.getCollection('collA').aggregate([
    {
        "$match":{
            // Some filter condition
        }
    },
    {
        "$project":{
            "_id":1,
            "fieldA":1,
            "fieldB":1,
            "fieldC":1
        }
    }
]);
```

Assume I am getting 10 records from collA

```
db.getCollection('collB').aggregate([
    {
        "$match":{
            // Some filter condition
        }
    },
    {
        "$project":{
            "_id":1,
            "fieldA":1,
            "fieldB":1,
            "fieldC":1
        }
    }
]);
```

Assume I am getting 5 records from collB

Now, what I want to do is I want to combine this 15 records and want to perform other aggregate operation like $group and many other things.

Is there any way to do this with mongoDB aggregation or any other alternative option?

Assume below schema for both collection

```
CollA
{
    fieldA : String,
    fieldB : String
    fieldC : String
    fieldD : String
}


CollB
{
    fieldA : String,
    fieldB : String
    fieldC : String
    fieldE : String
}
```

Comment: Do they have any DB refs? Col1 & Col2?

Comment: The only way you can query two collections using aggregate is if they have db refs?

Comment: can you please post your all the collection here

Comment: @CaptainJackSparrow No there is no db reference between them.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I have updated description with schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

Here, Firstly you need to put [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) to get the single document from the aggregate collection... Then [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to processes multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage on the same set of input documents... Now need to perform [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation to get data from other collections with limit of 5 and 10... Concat the two array getting from [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) using [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) and then simply [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) it and replace it with new root `data` using [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$limit": 1 },
  { "$facet": {
    "collectionA": [
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Collection.name,
        "pipeline": [
          { "$limit": 5 }
        ],
        "as": "collectionA"
      }},
      { "$project": { "collectionA": 1, "_id": 0 }},
      { "$unwind": "$collectionA" },
      { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$collectionA" } }
    ],
    "collectionB": [
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Collection.name,
        "pipeline": [
          { "$limit": 10 }
        ],
        "as": "collectionB"
      }},
      { "$project": { "collectionB": 1, "_id": 0 }},
      { "$unwind": "$collectionB" },
      { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$collectionB" } }
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "data": {
      "$concatArrays": [ "$collectionA", "$collectionB" ]
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" } }
  // Here you can perform your other operations //
])
```